# Android EditText weird height issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I can't really explain this, so I'll use an image:

[image: height problem]

OK, so as you can see, the actual `EditText` View is slightly taller than the actual white (editable area). How is this? I've removed all padding and margin that View has and still it looks bad.

Also I have another 2 problems with this `EditText` view when deploying it on the device:

1. It automatically captures focus (how can I disable this?)
2. When focusing it, there is an orange border, but the actual editable area is wider than the orange borders (see screenshot 2):

[image]

Comment: You should modify your edittext's background... You can set a selector to modify it how to look when it's focused, pressed, enabled, disable and etc.

Comment: Did you looked at the nine path images used for the `EditText`'s background in the SDK?

Comment: Are you using a 9Patch image or is it the default background?(I assume the default one right?)

Comment: And about the padding, that is default background of edittext which as i know cannot be removed unless you set a selector as i said.

Comment: The background is the default one. I'm aware of 9Patch images, but don't know how they work, so didn't do that. Fixed the problem in the 2nd image, by re-adding the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the background of the pre Holo EditText:

[image]

And here is the background of the pre Holo EditText when its selected:

[image]

As you can see, those 9Patches already have paddings in them. So you the height of the EditText won't be the same as the height of the actual editable area. I would recommend you to set the height to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the padding in the 9Patch isn't equal on all sides. On the bottom it's more, and that's the reason I can't vertically align the EditText.